# How to update Python version on Spyder?

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I'm using Spyder IDE using Python 3.7.5. I want to switch to Python 3.8, what should I do?

Answer (score 7):

If you're using Anaconda, you need to create a conda environment for it like this:

`conda create -n py38 python=3.8 spyder-kernels`

Then you need to open Spyder and go to the menu

`Tools > Preferences > Python interpreter`

select the option `Use the following Python interpreter` and select the Python executable of your `py38` environment.

You can find more information about this procedure [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder).

Comment: Then please stay with Python 3.7

Comment: if possible, could you please take a look at my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72937044/10841085) at your convenience? I'm getting different results in Spyder and IDLE for the same version of Python (v3.10). I'm not sure if this is because I've installed the interpreter incorrectly in Spyder.

Answer (score 0):

in v5.0.2 ...

```
Tools / Preferences / Python interpreter
```

then select

```
'Use the following Python interpreter'
```

and browse to the `python.exe` you want and '`apply`'
you'll need to restart Spyder.

NB your version of python will need to have the spyder package installed.

```
pip install spyder-kernels==2.0.*
```